# Windows 7, quick lauch on task bar placed left

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, taskbar, quicklaunch

I have to move to Windows 7 from XP. I'm used to launch applications from quick launch in task bar. So, to be able to have several icons in quick launch, I placed task bar at left in XP. 
That's how it looks like in XP:

[image: http://s30.postimg.org/skja9p0ep/quick_Launch_XP.jpg]

Now, I'm trying to do the same in Windows 7, but it only allows one icon per row (instead of three or more, depending on width of taskbar, in XP):

[image: http://s14.postimg.org/mv3vsz6j5/2014_11_27_13_45_24.jpg]

Is there a way to achieve same behavior in Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your QuickLaunch is not really QuickLaunch. You have icons pinned to Task Bar.

I have something like this when I move bar to left:

[image]

This is how I enabled normal Quick Launch: [Microsoft Support link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/975784/en-us)

I also unpinned all icons from taskbar and changed many options in taskbar properties. Now it acts just like XP taskbar.

Comment: Did not know the concept of pinned icons. That is what I've been looking for. Nice xD

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that is possible.  However, you're not the first to ask for that.  There appears to be a [work around](https://superuser.com/questions/517701/windows-7-side-taskbar-how-to-have-multiple-icon-columns) that provides something similar.

Comment: Although it's discouraged: Thanks. I really googled, but I wasn't able to figure out the appropriated way to ask.

Comment: I think you missunderstood question. It is possible to add Quick Launch to Windows 7 and it acts like Quick Launch in XP. See my answer.